# Mouse click on a background window without moving mouse c++

Tags: c++, vb.net

I need to know if there is a code in c++ that allows to simulate a click, on a background window (if that's impossible, a foreground window will do fine), without moving the mouse.

I also need to click on specific coordinates, and drag an item to some other position (always without moving the mouse).

Example:
my mouse pointer is at (500,700),
but i need to left click at (100,150),
and drag to (700,300).

I need to be able to move my mouse pointer without affecting the program,
and the program must run correctly without moving, or locking, the mouse pointer.

If this action is impossible in c++, a VB code will be apreciated.

Comment: I suppose that with *c++* you mean c++/cli, not standard c++. I'm correct?

Comment: Emh... Sorry but i dont really know what that means, i just make programs for hobby =P, but any help will be apreciated. I use dev cpp if this can be usefull to you. Thanks

Comment: @Target - Basically, c++/cli is the .NET version of c++ - the `cli` part stands for Common Language Infrastructure - it uses many of the same componenets that VB.NET and C# use. (You can't use any of them with DevC++). Incidently, you may be able to achieve something with SendMouseInput - the cursor will still move, though you _may possibly_ be able to do the whole operation fast enough that the user doesn't notice. I used it when following a tute to make a `Minesweeper bot` to play the MS Windows game, minesweeper flawlessly (a custom max-size board solved in under 1 sec).

Comment: In Windows, mouse clicks are sent by messages.  You should be able to send a mouse click message to another Window.

Comment: well i can't do the mouse movement too fast, because the game will not even accept it, so i need to put a delay between the drag and drop code, i could event try another program instead of devC++, i'll like to know if there is actually a code to do that actions without moving the mouse(even in other programming languages), I tryed SendInput and SendMessage and PostMessage, but that was not very usefull... To be honest i'm trying to make a "Bot", that makes some actions on my computer... nothing "criminal" :)

Answer (score 0):

From a C++ Windows application, you can call Windows API directly by first finding the window using [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that will give you the window handle you want, then finding the area within this window that you want to click. You can use API like [GetWindowRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this.
Finally, you can send this window, or an area within it, mouse messages using [mouse_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to cause the mouse to move, click, drag and let go at a new location.

Comment: I already know hot to found the window Handle, but i didn't yet figured out how to make the mouse part, because mouse_event moves the mouse cursor. Could you please make me an example on how to make a drag and drop of an item, without moving the mouse, and how to apply that to another window by using it's handle ? Thanks